# link from a web page to facebook messenger with a token

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a web app where user can open sort of a ticket.
I would like to create a link from this web app to facebook messenger (ideally to a mobile app via deep link) bot (by my page) in a way so that the user after starting chat or choosing an option in the messenger can be automatically matched with an existing ticket opened in that web app. Wondering if this is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

there's actually a rasa chatbot template like this in [github](https://github.com/cedextech/rasa-chatbot-templates). check out the 10_freshdesk_customer_support_bot sample project.

It's using RASA and call serviceNow APIs using actions.